# Linking mySQL database on MAMP server with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm extremely new at php and I'm trying to test if I can make a connection to my database. I use MAMP, and my MAMP ports are all at 8888 (idk if that makes a difference). To log into the local server with the mysql command lineboth my user and password is root. I am trying to see if the database Engineeringcareers can be connected. The page is stuck trying to load. If I only put echo 'xxx' then xxx shows up so the issue isn't if the php would run. It's the connection.

Is my code wrong here? I've tried many approaches

```html
<?php
$dbhost='localhost:8888';
$dbuser ='root';
$dbpassword ='root';
$dbdatabase= 'Engineeringcareers';


$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);

if (!$link) {
    die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($dbdatabase, $connection);

if(!db_selected) {
    die('cant use ' . $dbdatabase . ':' . mysql_error());
}

echo ' connected';
```

On a side note. Does anyone have any particular source that they go to to find out how to create a form with html and link it to the mysql database with php? I'm trying to learn how to do this, hopefully after I get the connection working.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You may find PHP easier to pick up and be effective for building applications if you to look at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) first to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: Port `8888` is your http port. Your MySQL port, unless changed from the default, is `3306`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove port 8888 and you are done, by default [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) which is an alias of [mysqli::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) uses port 3306 to connect to mysql, if you are running mysql on another port than 3306 you have to assign it like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase, $port);
```

**EDIT:** By default apache uses port 80 and mysql uses 3306, if you are running apache on port 8888 it doesn't mean that your database is available on port 8888 too, that's because each service can only use a unique port to communicate with other services.

Hope this helps

Comment: You can start by [creating a crud app using php and mysqli](http://codersfolder.com/2016/08/simple-crud-with-php-mysqli/)

Answer (score 1):

Your dbhost should be localhost, as pointed out by YouneL

```
$dbhost='localhost';
```

Here, you can refer to this link for an example on how to create a form with html and link it to the mysql database with php. - https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-php-mysql-contact-form/

Answer (score 0):

Give `localhost` only in `$dbhost` and connect `MYSQLi` like below:

```
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser ='root';
$dbpassword ='root';
$dbdatabase= 'Engineeringcareers';

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);

// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Print host information
echo "Connect Successfully. Host info: " . $mysqli->host_info;
```